# How to do a POVM measurement of a quantum state in IBM's Quantum Composer?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

I'm new to IBM, so I'm still figuring things out. I want to make a POVM measurement of a quantum state for state discrimination purposes. In other words I want a measurement that has three outcomes:

A: It's state A with 100 % certainty (or x %)
B: It's state B with 100 % certainty (or x %)
C: Can't determine if it's state A or B.

Can anyone help with how to do this in IBM's Quantum Composer?

Comment: The general idea is that you have to dilate your POVM into a projective measurement, as described in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM). An specific implementation for a quantum computer using qubits is described in [this exercise sheet](http://www.thp.uni-koeln.de/gross/qinfoexercises/sheet03.pdf).